# Where do i find a button?

Tags: vertices, customization

Can someone help me to enable this button?
I have the same version as the one in the photo but i cant find this button, i think it may need to be enabled from somewhere.

[image]

---

Here's the button im'm looking for.
[image]

Here's how my window looks like.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The x-ray button should be always visible. Could you please add a screenshot of *your* viewport?

Comment: I dont need the X-ray button i need the one im pointing in the image i've atached.

Comment: That button is used to select the vertices behind the mesh, i don't know exactly how that function is called.

Comment: I've added below 2 screenshots :)

Comment: Just to point out - they're not the same versions, just very similar :). The first one is 2.8 Alpha and the second one probably 2.82. Thats why the icon is different.

Comment: Thank you very much.